# Quotient of Dedekind domain with prime ideal

Tags: number-theory

Let K be a number field. Then Z_K, the ring of integers, is a Dedekind domain. For all nonzero prime ideals p, the quotient Z_K/p is a finite field.

I understand that in Z_K, every prime ideal is maximal, and so Z_K/p is not only an integral domain, but a field. What I don't understand is why is it a finite field? I see it works in Z as Z/pZ is a finite field for 
prime p. How does this generalise to prime ideals of Z_K?

Comment: Hmm, the usual proof I have seen actually shows that the quotient by any non-zero prime ideal is finite in order to prove them maximal.

Comment: Why is it necessarily finite?

Comment: If $K$ is a number field, then $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is a finite extension.

Comment: You should show that $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a finite $\mathbb{Z}$-module, so if $\mathfrak{p}$ non-zero prime of $\mathcal{O}_K$ lies over $p$, $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}$ is a finite $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Comment: @CaptainLama the dimension of that module can't be greater than $[K:\mathbb{Q}]$ which is finite

Comment: From what I understand, is it because Z_K is finite-dimensional Z-module, since all bases of K/Q are finite from the definition of a number field, and all Z-bases of Z_K belong to the set of bases for K/Q?

Comment: @PITTALUGA sure, but this is not such an obvious fact, and is the heart of the proof. In general, you may have a ring $A$ with fraction field $K$, a finite field extension $L/K$ such that if $B$ is the integral closure of $A$ in $L$, $B$ is not a finite $A$-module. Even if $A$ is noetherian. So in the above case you also have to use that $A$ is integrally closed in $K$. Of course everything is simpler if $A=\mathbb{Z}$ because it is principal, but what I mean is that the result is not completely formal.

Comment: @Richard it is true that you may find a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of $\mathcal{O}_K$ which is a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis of $K$, but you will have to use that $\mathbb{Z}$ is principal. It is not true if you replace $\mathbb{Z}$ with a Dedekind ring for instance (which are already very good rings), even with the ring of integers of a number field.